# Why is the extension $L/F$ in the proof is normal$?$

Tags: galois-theory

[image]

In proof of part $(1)$ of this preposition, $L/F$ is a galois extension. However, I didn't understand why. It is a separable extension. But how can one prove the normality$?$

Here, $E/F$ is a finite separable extension of degree $n$.
$σ_1, . . . , σ_n $ are the $F-$embeddings $: E → F^a$ $(F^a $is algebraic closure of$ F)$
$N_{E/K}(a) = σ_1(a)σ_2(a)· · · σ_n(a)$

I think there is a typo in the proof. $L$ should be $\sigma_1(E) \sigma_2(E)....\sigma_n(E)$ instead.

Comment: You want $\sigma_1,\dots,\sigma_n$ to be the $F$-embeddings into some fixed algebraic closure of $F$ rather, yes?

Comment: Yes, edited the problem.

Comment: If the notation $\sigma_{1}(F)...\sigma_{n}(F)$ is meant to indicate compositum, it should be clear: this by definition contains all possible roots for any given polynomial with a root in $L$, as all roots should be captured by different embeddings, giving you normality.

Comment: To explain the proof, the context is relevant. What is the definition of normal extension given in the book?

Comment: Here it is-An algebraic extension $ E/F$ is called a normal extension if whenever $ f(x)
\in F[x]$ is irreducible and has a root in $ E$ then $ f(x)$ splits into linear factors in $ E[x].$

Comment: $\sigma 's$ are just $F$ embeddings, so $\sigma (F) =F$, then why compositum of $\sigma_i (F)$ is taken, it should be just F.

Comment: What if $L$ is $σ_1(E)σ_2(E)....σ_n(E) $ instead.$?$